# The set $A=\{0\} \cup \{\frac 1n \mid n \in \mathbb N\}$

Tags: general-topology

For the set $A=\{0\} \cup \{\frac 1n \mid n \in \mathbb N\}$, I understand that $\{\frac 1n \mid n \in \mathbb N\}$ is open and closed in $A$ because it is a union of all the connected components $\{\frac 1n\}$ in $A$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$. Even though $\{0\}$ is also a connected component of $A$, why is $\{0\}$ closed but not open? I thought $\{0\}$ is closed and open in $A$ as well just like each $\{\frac 1n\}$.

Comment: To define what it means to be an open subset of $A$, you need to define the topology on $A$.  You may be taking the discrete topology, but reading your question, it's hard to tell.

Comment: I'm assuming this is with the sub space topology of $\mathbb{R}$. I think you're confusion comes from the fact that $\{0\}$ is not actually a connected component. In any open neighborhood of 0 you can always find other points in $A$.

Comment: To put a finer point on what @Tbraz says, in the $\mathbb R$ subspace topology $\{1/n\mid n\in \mathbb N\}$ is open in $A$ but not closed.

Answer (score 1):

Viewing A as a subspace of R, since {0} is closed,
within A, B = A - {0} is open.  B is not closed within A 
because 0 is an adherance point of B that is not in B.

Using the clumbsy definition of closed, B is not closed
within A because 0 is a limit point of B that is not in B.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be an uncountable set with the cocountable topology. As all convergent sequences in $X$ are eventually constant and then have that constant as its limit, all subsets are sequentially closed. But only $X$ and at most countable subsets are closed.

Answer (score 0):

If $\{0\}$ is open then there must exist some $\epsilon>0$ such that $$\{x\in A:|x|<\epsilon\}\subseteq\{0\}$$if such an $\epsilon$ exists we must have $$\{\dfrac{1}{n}:n>\dfrac{1}{\epsilon}\}\subseteq\{0\}$$which doesn't hold at all then the set is not open